# Either and inner Maybe error handling

Tags: haskell, error-handling, option-type, either

Is there a Haskell pattern that obviates the writing of this custom function? The idea being to handle the Nothing from Maybe as an error (as part of the wrapping Either):

```
eitherMaybeHandle :: String -> Either String (Maybe a) -> Either String a
eitherMaybeHandle err = \case
  Left e ->
    Left e
  Right Nothing ->
    Left err
  Right (Just a) ->
    Right a
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you can use `sequence` to turn an `Either a (Maybe b)` into a `Maybe (Either a b)`. Then you can apply `fromMaybe` to the result along with your value of type `a` in order to get an `Either a b`.

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

eitherMaybeHandle :: a -> Either a (Maybe b) -> Either a b
eitherMaybeHandle err = fromMaybe (Left err) . sequence
```

Comment: Why does it make sense to convert `Either a (Maybe b)` (which tells a story: you will definitely get an `a`, but if there would be `b`, it gonna be preferred) to the quite confusing `Maybe (Either a b)`, telling **totally different** story: you might get something or not. Am new to Haskell, but not to FP. So just curious why you consider that one as a good solution? (Anyway, +1).

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov I consider it a good solution because it's short and relatively readable if you're familiar with these functions. The other answers here are also pretty readable. In terms of their story, `Either a (Maybe b)` and `Maybe (Either a b)` are isomorphic (meaning they contain the same amount of data), but `Maybe` has more built-in functions.

Comment: No they are not. Having `Maybe` might actually mean that you got nothing. In such a way you can NOT go back to `a` which was guaranteed by the `Either a (Maybe b)`.

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov Using `Either a (Maybe b)`, you can also have nothing by using `Right Nothing`. Since there's a one to one mapping between every possible value, they're isomorphic.

Comment: one-to-one is an injective mapping. you need surjection as well to get a bijection (which is 'isomorphism').

Comment: @SerejaBobolubov The one to one relationship goes both ways, so it's bijective as well. Could you give a counter-example?

Comment: bool -> int might be one-to-one, but in such a case there are 2^32 - 2 integers, having which you can't go back. checkout carefully what is surjection (else known as 'onto' mapping).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164367/discussion-between-4castle-and-sereja-bobolubov).

Answer (score 3):

The original code is already fine. You might want to consider making it occupy fewer lines by keeping each branch on the same line.

Otherwise, just for the sake of alternatives, you could use:

```
eitherMaybeHandle :: String -> Either String (Maybe a) -> Either String a
eitherMaybeHandle _   (Left e)         = Left e
eitherMaybeHandle err (Right Nothing)  = Left err
eitherMaybeHandle _   (Right (Just a)) = Right a
```

or even

```
eitherMaybeHandle :: String -> Either String (Maybe a) -> Either String a
eitherMaybeHandle _   (Left e)  = Left e
eitherMaybeHandle err (Right x) = maybe (Left err) Right x
```

I'd consider the original code to be more readable than the latter alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the most simpel function, but an attempt using monads and the `Maybe` *catamorphism* like:

```
import Data.Maybe(maybe)

eitherMaybeHandle :: a -> Either a (Maybe b) -> Either a b
eitherMaybeHandle err = (>>= maybe (Left err) Right)
```

We can even drop the `err` parameter, and write it like:

```
eitherMaybeHandle :: a -> Either a (Maybe b) -> Either a b
eitherMaybeHandle = (=<<) . flip maybe Right . Left
```

Since `Either a` is a monad instance, we can thus use `>>=`. In that case, we leave the `Left x` untouched, and the `Right x` is passed through the function.

As function we use `maybe :: a -> (b -> a) -> Maybe b -> a`. So we map `Nothing` on `Left err`, and we use `Right` as a function to transform `Just x`, in `Right x`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [`errors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors) package, which offers

```
note :: a -> Maybe b -> Either a b
```

which can be combined with another `Either` with the `Monad` instance:

```
eitherMaybeHandle :: e -> Either e (Maybe a) -> Either e a
eitherMaybeHandle err act = act >>= note err
```

Comment: Note that as simple as `note x = maybe (Left x) Right`

Comment: @phadej Definitely. But often when I find myself needing to promote `Maybe` to `Either`, I find myself needing to do many other kinds of translations between error-reporting mechanisms nearby, so dragging in the whole package is frequently worth it.